# PowerShell XAML | Update Style Programmatically Failing

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm writing a simple automation tool that flips the color of a button using the button styles, but in PowerShell the button just resets back to Windows default style. I've tried googling, but I keep finding answers that don't simply work anymore (likely due to newer PS5).

Here is my code for both:

PowerShell

```
## v0.09 New CORE ##############
################################
$dev = $true
$ver = 0.09

$DIR_APP = $PSScriptRoot

cls
## Console
################################################################
$Script:showWindowAsync = Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
"@ -Name "Win32ShowWindowAsync" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru

if(!$DEV){ $null = $showWindowAsync::ShowWindowAsync((Get-process -Id $pid).MainWindowHandle, 0); }

function Get-KeyState([uint16]$k)
{
  $s = '[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern short GetKeyState(int nVirtKey);'
  $t = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $s -Name User32 -Namespace GetKeyState -PassThru
  return [bool]($t::GetKeyState($k) -band 0x80)
}


## Startup Framework
################################################################
Add-Type -Assembly PresentationFramework
Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore

$app = [Windows.Application]::New()

[xml]$XAML = Get-Content ($DIR_APP + "\Z4.xaml")
$Read = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML);
try{ $Script:core = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Read) }catch{ write-host "[ERR]::XAML >> CORE_MAIN" -f "red"; exit; }
$XAML.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{ Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Script:core.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Script; }

$core.Add_Activated({ Initialization })

## Framework
################################################################
function Initialization()
{
  # Button = 2 + INCOMPLETE
  $coreAppName.Text = "Core v" + $ver;
  
  $coreClose.Add_Click({ $core.Close(); });
  $coreTest.Add_Click({ ClickTest });

    $core.show();
}

## Application
################################################################


## GUI
################################################################
function ClickTest()
{
  $coreTest.Style = $core.tryFindResource("BlueMe");
}

$app.Run($core);
```

XAML

````
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  
    Title=""
    MinWidth="1"
    MinHeight="1"
    
    UseLayoutRounding="True"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    
    Topmost="True"
    Background="#111"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    WindowStyle="None">
  
  <Grid Background="#111" Margin="4">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4, 4, 0, 0"/>
            </Style>
            
            <Style x:Key="CloseRed" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#111"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="23"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#300"/>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
            
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#222"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333"/>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
      
      <Style x:Key="BlueMe" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#138"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
              <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="0">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#14A"/>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>

      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#222"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4, 0, 4, 0"/>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="coreAppName" Text="Core" Margin="4,2" FontSize="12"/>
    <Button    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="coreClose" Style="{StaticResource CloseRed}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Path Margin="-8,-8,0,0" Fill="#F00" Data="M 26.9166,22.1667L 37.9999,33.25L 49.0832,22.1668L 53.8332,26.9168L 42.7499,38L 53.8332,49.0834L 49.0833,53.8334L 37.9999,42.75L 26.9166,53.8334L 22.1666,49.0833L 33.25,38L 22.1667,26.9167L 26.9166,22.1667 Z">
        <Path.LayoutTransform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.4" ScaleY="0.4"/>
        </Path.LayoutTransform>
      </Path>
    </Button>
    
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="coreTest" Content="Test" Width="96" Height="48"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a bunch of trial and error (and reading the MS XAML KB).

The Style and Key must be in Window.Resources for $core.tryFindResource("Key") to find it.